# Use scalar from pandas series in string for plot label

Tags: python, pandas, string, label, histogram

Apologies if this question is a duplicate, I also thought it would have been easy to find an answer... So my issue is actually more generally about inserting a value from series object into a string, but it occurs in the context of a histogram with an added line for the median where I want the legend for the median line to display the actual median. Here is toy data

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'age': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
                          '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14',
                          '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21']})
```

And stripped code to get the graph

```
color = '#003366'
color2 = '#fc4f30'

ages = df['age']
bins = np.arange(5, 100, 2).tolist()
median_age = df['age'].median()

plt.hist(ages, bins=bins, color=color, edgecolor='black', alpha= 0.9)
plt.axvline(median_age, color=color2, label='Age Median', linewidth=2)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I would like to modify the passage `label='Age Median'` to be `label='Age Median = df['age'].median()'` but I don't get how to insert the scalar into the string. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, one way of doing this is inserting `{:.2f}` into the string and then adding `.format(median_age)` after the string.

```
plt.axvline(median_age, color=color2, label="Age Median = {:.2f}".format(median_age), linewidth=2)
```

Note: `{:.2f}` is the formatting of the number and gives two decimals.

Ref: https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/string_formatting.html